# replace phases of fsck in fstab

Tags: sed, fstab, fsck

I'm searching some way to replace fsck phases in my fstab file but only for line which contains specific path.

currently fstab looks like that:

```
/dev/mapper/vgroot-root /          xfs          defaults          0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-home /home          xfs          defaults          0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-opt /opt          xfs          defaults          0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-var /var          xfs          defaults          0 0
/dev/mapper/vgapp-optapp /opt/apt          xfs          defaults          0 0

192.168.1.1:/app/rep_t1 /data/rep_t1          nfsrep_t1 defaults          0 0
192.168.1.1:/app/rep_t1 /data/rep_t1          nfsrep_t1 defaults          0 0
```

I would like to change phases from "0 0" to "1 2" but only for local filesystem (/dev/mapper). How can i do that? Currenly i'm able to change only 1 value like below:

```
sed -i -e '/mapper/ s/0/1/' /etc/fstab
```

Here is how it should be:

```
/dev/mapper/vgroot-root /          xfs          defaults          1 2
/dev/mapper/vgroot-home /home          xfs          defaults          1 2
/dev/mapper/vgroot-opt /opt          xfs          defaults          1 2
/dev/mapper/vgroot-var /var          xfs          defaults          1 2
/dev/mapper/vgapp-optapp /opt/apt          xfs          defaults          1 2

192.168.1.1:/app/rep_t1 /data/rep_t1          nfsrep_t1 defaults          0 0
192.168.1.1:/app/rep_t1 /data/rep_t1          nfsrep_t1 defaults          0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close:

```
sed -i '/mapper/ s/0 0/1 2/' /etc/fstab
```

See [this excellent sed tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) if you want to learn more.